# Transmitting variables via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, variables

I am working at a calendar at the moment. Next to the calendar I want to have a description box in which some more informations about the event should be displayed when the user clicks on the date in the calendar.

What I have until now:
HTML/PHP:

```
// Variables from MySQL request:    
$event
$date
$place
$start
$end

<button type="button" onclick="event_description()">$day</button>

<div id="details"></div>
```

AJAX:

```
function event_description() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "kalender/description.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

So what can I do so I can use the MySQL variables in the description.php?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you named function as `kalendar_description` and bind `event_description`

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. in my script it was correct, it was just all in an other language so i made a mistake translating it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this..

```
// Variables from MySQL request:        
$event
$date
$place

///pass all the parameters in onclick function as arguments 

<button type="button" onclick="event_description('<?php echo $event ?>','<?php echo $date ?>','<?php echo $place ?>')">$day</button>
<div id="details"></div>
```

Script code

```
<script>
///get all the params here in function
function event_description(event_name,date,place) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };

  /////create a string of all the parameters and pass this with requested url as query string and get all these params in target file using `$_GET[]`

  var params = 'event_name='+event_name+'&date='+date+'&place='+place;
  xhttp.open("GET", "kalender/description.php?"+params, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @DanGreen You're welcome, Glad to help you... ;) up vote my answer if it is really helpful for you.. Thankx..